# How to take difference between two values of a key in dictionary and store it in another new key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to take difference between values of a particular key in two dictionary based on some conditions and then store the result in a new key in the same dictionary. A sample is provided below:

```
A = {'a':10,'b':abc,'c':''}
B = {'a':80,'b':def,'c':''}
C = {'a':20,'b':xyz,'c':''}
```

After checking the condition for key 'b', I need to update dictionary B with its value of key 'c' with the difference of values of key 'a' in dictionaries A and B. My desired output should look like:

```
 Condition: the values of key 'b' should be 'abc' and 'def'. 

B = {'a':80,'b':def,'c':70}
```

I used below function but it threw syntax error.

```
dict2 = {'d':''}
for dic in dictionary:
   dic.update(dict2)

def func(dictionary):
 for dic in dictionary:
      if dic['b'] == 'def':
          if dic['b'] == 'abc':
              dic['d'] = dic['b']
      dic['c'] = dic['a'].subtract(dic['d'])
 return dictionary
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Let me know if more details are required on this question.

The traceback below has different file names and attributes. But attaching for your reference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-3d57363f374c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/msharma/Desktop/Python CSV files/Notification to Chargeback.py', wdir='C:/Users/msharma/Desktop/Python CSV files')

  File "C:\Users\msharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\msharma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/msharma/Desktop/Python CSV files/Notification to Chargeback.py", line 69, in <module>
not_to_chb(dicts)

  File "C:/Users/msharma/Desktop/Python CSV files/Notification to Chargeback.py", line 66, in not_to_chb
dic['Conversion Period'] = dic['of Difference in week'].subtract(dic['Week of NotificationOfFraud'])

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'subtract'
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried? Can you show your coding attempt for this please and explain what is currently not working out for you?

Comment: Edit your question and put your code in there please. And ensure it is properly formatted.

Comment: What is the syntax error? Please provide the full Traceback. Copy paste it in to your question please.

Comment: I am surprised! People just love to give downvote. I didn't know asking a question is a bad thing here. :)

@idjaw I have attached the traceback and my code for your reference.

Comment: `dic['b']` can't simultaneously equal `'abc'` and `'def'` in your function, so your conditions will never evaluate to both true. Which doesn't matter because your `subtract` line lives outside of your conditionals. And it's not clear why you'd expect a `subtract` function on a float value. A simple `dic['a'] - dic['d']` would work, except then you'll get a `KeyError` because there's no `'d'` in `dic`

Comment: @MohitSharma The reason why there were downvotes is because your question was lacking the minimum information at first. Please revise how to put together an [mcve] and how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: @JCVanHamme thanks for your suggestion. I think i got my mistake.
idjaw thanks for your advice. Will keep it in mind from now onwards. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if A['b'] == 'abc' and B['b'] == 'def':
    B['c'] = B['a'] - A['a']
```

Comment: def cannot be used as a variable name

Comment: Good catch. Edited to fix.

Comment: Probably, you need to add an explanation describing the source of the problem and how your answer fixes the issue...